# How do you create a 2X5 matrix from a text file in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to obtain a 5X2 matrixfrom a text file.

For **Example :**

```
0_0     1_0
0_200   1_200
0_400   1_400
0_600   1_600
0_800   1_800
```

This is the **code** I am currently using:

```
[filename,pathname]= uigetfile({'*.txt'});
set(handles.temp1,'String',fullfile(pathname,filename));
chosenfile=get(handles.temp1,'String');

fid=fopen(chosenfile);

allcoordinates=textscan(fid,'%s,%s','whitespace','\n');    
fclose(fid);
```

This code would produce a 5X1 matrix as shown below :

```
 0_01_0
 0_2001_200
 0_4001_400
 0_6001_600
 0_8001_800
```

Comment: Can you describe your wanted result of reading?

Comment: Use underscore '_' as delimiter in textscan

Comment: Matlab has a nice gui for data import. Try that. It will also write the code for you on the press of a button.

Answer (score 3):

Sadly, the approach that works best with interpretation of files, is to be **very conservative** with relying on the capabilities of 'canned routines' like `textscan`, `dlmread` and similar.

This is not because these routines are implemented badly, it's because there is very little standardization in number formatting in text files, and basically, everybody just invents a new standard on the spot.

You just can't design a routine that always works correctly for all text files. I think The Mathworks did a very decent job with their `dlmread` and similar, however, you have just presented *yet another* standard in number formatting that is overly difficult to interpret in one go with `textscan` or `dlmread` or others. Therefore, be conservative: just read it without too much hassle, and do the conversion yourself.

For example:

```
%// Read data
fid = fopen('yourFile.txt', 'r');
    C = textscan(fid, '%s %s');
fclose(fid);

%// Replace all underscores with '.', and convert to 'double'    
C = str2double(strrep([C{:}],'_','.'))
```

Results:

```
C =
         0    1.0000
    0.2000    1.2000
    0.4000    1.4000
    0.6000    1.6000
    0.8000    1.8000
```